# Java GUI: JPanel add multiple identical Panels

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jpanel

So right now i am learning how to code the GUI in java. What I was trying to do was to make a GUI for players of a card game showing their name,icon and number of cards in hand for now. However I have encountered a problem where it does not work as i expected where i assumed that it could possibly add 13 identical panels within the outer JPanel. Below are the codes, thanks!:

```
public JPanel createNested(int i) {

    ImageIcon image;
    JPanel outer = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,14));
    JPanel inner = new JPanel();
    JPanel deck = new JPanel();
    JLabel cards = new JLabel(cardBackImage);
    inner.setLayout(new BoxLayout(inner, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    JLabel name = new JLabel("Player" + i);
    image = avatars[i];
    JLabel icon = new JLabel(avatars[i]);
    outer.setBackground(Color.green);
    inner.setBackground(Color.green);
    deck.setBackground(Color.green);
    deck.add(cards);

    inner.add(name);
    inner.add(icon);
    outer.add(inner);
    for(int k=0;k<13;k++){
        outer.add(deck);
    }
    return outer;
  }
```

What i expected:
[name&icon][card][card][card][card][card][card][card][card][card][card][card][card][card]

What i see:
[name&icon].............................................................................[card]

(The dots represents blanks)

Answer (score 2):

You can't add one instance of a JPanel multiple times. You should be creating a new JPanel for each deck like this:

```
for(int k=0;k<13;k++){
    JPanel deck = new JPanel();
    JLabel cards = new JLabel(cardBackImage);
    deck.setBackground(Color.green);
    deck.add(cards);
    outer.add(deck);
}
```